# Using WDS to deploy the same image to different labs with different answer files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, deployment, wds

I'm planning on switching from a custom solution for our imaging to Microsoft WDS on 2008R2 servers with a 2008R2 DFL in our labs on campus.

What I need to know is how do I use a different answer file for each lab? I plan on using the .wim from the install media with just a few drivers added, so I'd have one image and control which software gets installed at imaging with different answer files per lab. As far as I can tell, I can only associate one answer file per image. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using MDt or straight WDS?

Comment: @Jim B - Straight WDS, but there's nothing stopping me from using MDT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run do not walk to the [download site for MDT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx).  You can set up task sequences based on any number of factors.  You may need or want to set up a webservice front end to allow additonal capabilities in Ad or simply use the roles portion of the MDT database.   [This part of a pretty good tutorial](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Deploying-Windows-7-Part16.html) talks about roles in the MDT database.  I also would reccomend this book [deployment fundamentals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451570031) If you have never used the MDT before